# How to create secrets manager secret resource policy that references the secret itself using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a terraform script that creates an AWS secrets manager secret with a resource based policy that grants an IAM role permissions to `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` on that specific secret.

I'm currently running into [Terraform cycle issue](https://serverfault.com/q/1005761/) between the secrets manager secret and the IAM policy document. Here's what my code looks like:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "this" {
  name = "mySecret"    
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  statement {
    sid = "ReadPermissions"
    principals {
      type = "aws"
      identifiers = [data.aws_iam_role.this.arn]
    }
    actions = ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"]
    resources = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.arn]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  name = "myRole"
}
```

What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy, it can create a resource policy instead of IAM policy.

Example:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy" "example" {
  secret_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.arn

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "EnableAnotherAWSAccountToReadTheSecret",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gary, creating the aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy resource decoupled aws_iam_policy_document and the secrets manager secret. This is exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, the exact ARN of the secrets manager secret within the resource policy is not necessary. Since it's a resource policy, using '*' would refer to the secret itself [as shown in AWS' documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-resource-policy/).